# angular $http vs jquery $ajax - dataType for angular?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angular-http

How can I set the ajax return data type in angular? For instance I can set it easily in jquery if I want the response data to be html.

jquery,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html"
});
```

angular,

```
$http({
  method: "get",
  url: "script.php",
  responseType: "html" // does not work
}).then(function(response) {
  $scope.form = response.data;
);
```

It always returns string or json but what about html or xml?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do??

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (and by extension https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType), there is no `responseType` as `html`. I suppose `document` should work though.

Comment: `document` returns an object. angular 'sucks' despite it is a perfect mvc.

Comment: Oh, I suppose we'd have to settle for just plain text and find a way to parse it into `html` manually.